# Differentiate LIVE(REAL) and RECORDED voice

Tags: sound-design, signal-processing, automation, electronics, programming

I am working on a project in which the system has to allow only the right person to access the vault. How can I make the system to understand and differentiate a recorded voice and a real human's voice?

Comment: can you specify what is your equipment please?

Comment: I have a signal generator, an op-amplifier, and a hogh frequency speaker. Now, I have to use a board intel galelio to process the signal and understand it.I also have a power amplifier and a microphone.

Comment: This is a difficult task. I believe the template voice, and the specimen would have to be acquired and compared at a high resolution if the recorded voice was good quality and played back through a full frequency accurate speaker, or faked through voice conversion. [The University of Alabama is working on this problem](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-hackers-could-steal-your-voice-access-your-bank-account-1521573).

Comment: @jonhatan -I think `Code64` is proposing a __security vault__ with __voice authentication__ (instead of a password), that denies access for a __recorded voice__ (fraudulent access). Banks around the world currently have this problem(well, very similar). It's an interesting question.

Comment: Playing back a recorded voice requires some kind of speaker, most likely part of a portable system. Most portable speakers have a fairly limited frequency response. That means one place to look for a way to tell live versus recorded would be high frequencies. If live human speech produces much information above say 18 kHz, it's unlikely that a recording would have that. If you can design an ultrasonic microphone into the security system and there is ultrasonic information in live speech, that might work.

Comment: Attempting web searches on ultrasonic content in human speech is very hard because ultrasonic imaging of the tongue, pharynx, and larynx is used by linguists studying speech generation. The best I could do is come up with a guess that fricatives and possibly sibilants may produce ultrasonic content that would likely be poorly reproduced by a portable recorder. You might have to reach out to experts and/or conduct your own research by recording with ultrasonic equipment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about sound design.